# Counting the distinct elements in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumeration

I have an array:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 8, 1, 9]
```

I want to display each unique element value and its associated element count like this:

```
1: 2
2: 1
3: 2
6: 1
8: 1
9: 1
```

So far I have:

```
a.sort.group_by { |x| x }
{
  1 => [
    [0] 1,
    [1] 1
  ],
  2 => [
    [0] 2
  ],
  3 => [
    [0] 3,
    [1] 3
  ],
  6 => [
    [0] 6
  ],
  8 => [
    [0] 8
  ],
  9 => [
    [0] 9
  ]
}
```

So each element of the Hash contains an array. I can use that array's count to get my answer, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to process the hash concisely.

Is this a horrible implementation?

```
a.sort.group_by { |x| x }.each {|x| puts "#{x[0]} #{x[1].count}" }
```

Comment: What is 'wrong' with the code shown? The implementation is perfectly fine, but not the 'most efficient' as additional arrays are created - but if there is no problem (and there will not be for any trivial data-set), Just Don't Worry About It. In any case, this problem just [finding a frequency count](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+frequency+count), coupled with a sort.

Comment: Anyway, another option (without the need of a dictionary of any sort) is to sort and then walk the resulting array counting the number of times the value does not chance between subsequent elements..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
a.inject({}) { |a,e| a[e] = (a[e] || 0) + 1; a }
 => {1=>2, 2=>1, 3=>2, 6=>1, 8=>1, 9=>1}
```

For example:

```
h = a.inject({}) { |a,e| a[e] = (a[e] || 0) + 1; a }
 => {1=>2, 2=>1, 3=>2, 6=>1, 8=>1, 9=>1} 
h.keys.sort.each { |k| puts "#{k}: #{h[k]}" }
1: 2
2: 1
3: 2
6: 1
8: 1
9: 1
```

From comments of others below:

```
a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,a| a[e] += 1 }
 => {1=>2, 2=>1, 3=>2, 6=>1, 8=>1, 9=>1}
```

Comment: It would be cleaner to use a counting hash (i.e., default value of zero). Also, you can get rid of that pesky `a` at the end by using [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object): `a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,a| a[e] += 1 } #=> {1=>2, 2=>1, 3=>2, 6=>1, 8=>1, 9=>1}`.

Comment: Rather than use `inject`, consider `each_with_object`. The second is a little faster, about 30%, which with big arrays adds up.

Answer (score 3):

Use `uniq` to get the unique array values and `sort` to sort them in ascending order. Then for each of these values `x`, display `a.count(x)`.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 8, 1, 9]
a.uniq.sort.each {|x| puts '%d: %d' % [x, a.count(x)] }
```

For greater efficiency, make a hash that maps a value to the number of times it appears in the array. An easy way to do this is to initialize a Hash object that maps keys to zero by default. Then you can increment each value's count by one as you iterate through the array.

```
counts = Hash.new(0)
a.each {|x| counts[x] += 1 }
counts.keys.sort.each {|x| puts '%d: %d' % [x, counts[x]] }
```

Comment: Good point. I've added an alternative approach with hashing. Now it's O(n), assuming O(1) hash operations.

Comment: Your second solution is fine, but it would be more Ruby-like to do as I suggested in my comment on Jim's answer, as it both creates and returns the hash in a single statement. Your answer is diminished by your first solution, because it does not return the requested hash. It would be better to write `Hash[a.map { |e| [e, a.count] }]
 #=> {1=>8, 2=>8, 3=>8, 6=>8, 8=>8, 9=>8}`. Either way, if you want to print the values of `h` by increasing key value, you can write `a.uniq...` as you have done, but that was not asked for.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful critique. I'm always interested in stylistic improvements.

Comment: Using `count` is going to be painful as the size of the array grows. It forces a complete walk of the array for every value resulting from `uniq`.

Comment: Hence my remark on using a hash for greater efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 8, 1, 9]

a.group_by{ |n| n } # => {1=>[1, 1], 2=>[2], 3=>[3, 3], 6=>[6], 8=>[8], 9=>[9]}
a.group_by{ |n| n }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.size ] } # => [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 2], [6, 1], [8, 1], [9, 1]]
```

Finally:

```
a.group_by{ |n| n }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.size ] }.to_h # => {1=>2, 2=>1, 3=>2, 6=>1, 8=>1, 9=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
module Enumerable
  def freq
    hash = Hash.new(0)
    each { |each| hash[each] += 1 }
    hash
  end
end
```

And then

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 8, 1, 9].freq
# => {1=>2, 2=>1, 3=>2, 6=>1, 8=>1, 9=>1}
```